# Complex comparisons on yesno filter?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm quite new at python/django.
I love django's templates, but there is one recurrent thing I cannot find

It's very common for me to have one conditional attribute on a (probably long) HTML tag. Most of the times that's an extra CSS class.

For example, let's say you have two links to switch languages, and you want to enable only one at a time. I find myself doing something like this:

```
{% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as l %}
<a href="/path/to/switch/to/spanish" 
   class="{% ifequal l.code "es" %} disable {% endifequal %}">
   <img src="/spanish/flag/url" alt="Spanish">
</a>
<a href="/path/to/switch/to/english" 
   class="{% ifequal l.code "en" %} disable {% endifequal %}">
   <img src="/english/flag/url" alt="English">
</a>
```

Other examples may be while rendering a list of items and checking for the "selected" one, etc.

On other languages I did this with a ternary operator, but I know that's considered "evil" on the python/django world :-)

I wonder if there's a way to leverage from the "yesno" filter. I've tried to do something like:

```
{{l.code=="es"|yesno:"disabled,"}}
```

But I couldn't get it to work... am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simply with your syntax in the code you posted:

```
{{l.code=="es"|yesno:"disabled,"}}
```

It's actually processed like:

```
{{ l.code=={{"es"|yesno:"disabled,"}} }}
```

(Note: that code doesn't work, it's just meant to illustrate how Django reads it)

What you want is a custom template tag that works like the `if` templatetag but returns like the `yesno` filter. You could search around on something like djangosnippets.com; maybe someone has already done the work for you. Otherwise, I'd suggest looking at the Django source code for those two and try to merge them into your own templatetag.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use jQuery/javascript to set the class:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/
something like this - not tested!

```
{% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as l %}

<script>
{% if l.code='es' %}
  $('.english').attr('class','disable');
{% else %}
  $('.english').attr('class','disable');
{% endif %}
</script>



<a href="/path/to/switch/to/spanish" 
   id="spanish" class='enable">
   <img src="/spanish/flag/url" alt="Spanish" >
</a>
<a href="/path/to/switch/to/english" 
   id="english" class='enable">
   <img src="/english/flag/url" alt="English">
</a>
```